# JAX-RS validation for string which may be empty or must have n digits

Tags: validation, jax-rs, bean-validation

I'm using the `Pattern` validation from `javax.validation.constratins` to validate a field. The string:

- may be `null` or empty OR
- it must have exactly seven digits.

I managed to validate for the seven digits but I can't figure out how to additionally validate that this field may be empty.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyRestRequest {

  @Pattern(regexp = "\\d{7}")
  private String someString;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) `null` is considered to be valid, problem boils down to construct regular expression that matches to empty String or to seven digits. Typically for empty string one uses `^$` (beginning and end of the line).

In this case also `^|\\d{7}` and `$|\\d{7}` or even `|\\d{7}` would work, but `^$|\\d{7}` is more typical:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^$|\\d{7}")
public String someString;
```